# Why do raw html template braces in Svelte produce empty noscript tags?

Tags: svelte

When using the {{{triple}}} curly brace syntax to output raw html from a string, I see a couple of noscript tags in the output from the compiler.

For instance:

```
<noscript></noscript><h1>Boom</h1><noscript></noscript>
```

Does anyone know why these tags are rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `foo` in a `{{{foo}}}` tag changes, Svelte needs to remove the existing DOM nodes before it can insert the new ones. Since it doesn't have references to the previously-inserted nodes (that would require additional indirection and book-keeping), it needs to know which DOM nodes immediately precede and follow `{{{foo}}}`.

In many situations, that's straightforward — if you have a template like this...

```html
<div>{{{foo}}}</div>
```

...then Svelte can simply do `div.innerHTML = foo`. If you have sibling nodes...

```html
<div>
  <span>before</span>
  {{{foo}}}
  <span>after</span>
</div>
```

...then Svelte can remove everything between `before` and `after`.

But if there are no guarantees about which nodes surround the tag...

```html
<div>
  {{#if x}}
    <span>maybe I exist, maybe I don't</span>
  {{/if}}

  {{{foo}}}

  {{#if y}}
    <span>ditto!</span>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

...then it becomes necessary to insert placeholder nodes that Svelte can use to ensure the DOM is updated correctly. `<noscript>` nodes are suitable because they have no effect in a browser with JavaScript enabled (which we know is the case if Svelte is running), but still have useful methods like `insertAdjacentHTML` (which comment nodes don't have).